# PHP hour calculation on 15 minutes interval and working hours in array never add up

Tags: php, arrays

I have a starttime and endtime, which always start or end on exact a hour :00 or :15, :30, :45.

For example:

```
00:30 21-05-2012 // startdate and time
18:15 22-05-2012 // enddate and time (+1 day)
```

I have to charge an extra % if the time falls into evening or night hours.

So I have 2 arrays, one for evening hours and one for night hours which looks like this.

```
$eveningHours = array(
    '18:00',
    '18:15',
    '18:30',
    // etcetera
    '00:00'
);
```

The above array basically covers the time from 18:00 - 00:00, since these hours are falling into a evening hours.

Same goes for night hours, they cover the time from 00:00 - 07:00.

Since the start time and end time always land on exact :00 or :15, :30, :45.. I run a loop between the start datetime and the end datetime with an interval of 15 minutes and then on each interval I check if the current intervaltime is night/evening hour and then Ii add +15 to a evening / night hour counter and at the end I divide this by 60 to get the total hours.

But somehow it always has 15 minutes to much or 15 minutes to little... I've tried almost everything and can't get it to work properly..

So for example the start time is 00:30 it already adds 15 minutes to the first interval:

00:30 (counter: +15)
00:45 (counter: +15)

Which totals 30 minutes, but if you work from 00:30 to 00:45 it should offcourse only be 15 minutes.. So that is the place where it goes wrong I think. I just need a way to fix it.. I've already tried so many things by starting the counter with -15 minutes, or check if the start or end time is between a hour range and then set the counter to -15 or + 15 minutes.. but this also goes wrong.

*EDIT* this is the basic of the loop:

```
$start_time = mktime($_POST['worked_start_hour'], $_POST['worked_start_min'], 0, date("m"), date("d", strtotime("+1 days")), date("Y")); // +1 day for testing purpose
$end_time   = mktime($_POST['worked_end_hour'], $_POST['worked_end_min'], 0, date("m"), date("d", strtotime("+2 days")), date("Y")); // +2 days for testing purpose

$date['start_h_i']  = date("Y-m-d H:i", $start_time); # Start date: yyyy-mm-dd hours:minutes
$date['end_h_i']    = date("Y-m-d H:i", $end_time);   # End date: yyyy-mm-dd hours:minutes

$counter['eveningMinutes'] = 0;
$counter['nightMinutes'] = 0;

$eveningHours = array(
  '18:00',
  '18:15',
  '18:30',
  '18:45',
  '19:00',
  '19:15',
  '19:30',
  '19:45',
  '20:00',
  '20:15',
  '20:30',
  '20:45',
  '21:00',
  '21:15',
  '21:30',
  '21:45',
  '22:00',
  '22:15',
  '22:30',
  '22:45',
  '23:00',
  '23:15',
  '23:30',
  '23:45',
  '00:00'

);


$nightHours = array(
    '00:00',
    '00:15',
    '00:30',
    '00:45',
    '01:00',
    '01:15',
    '01:30',
    '01:45',
    '02:00',
    '02:15',
    '02:30',
    '02:45',
    '03:00',
    '03:15',
    '03:30',
    '03:45',
    '04:00',
    '04:15',
    '04:30',
    '04:45',
    '05:00',
    '05:15',
    '05:30',
    '05:45',
    '06:00',
    '06:15',
    '06:30',
    '06:45',
    '07:00'
);

while (strtotime($date['start_h_i']) <= strtotime($date['end_h_i'])) {

    if (in_array(date("H:i", strtotime($date['start_h_i'])), $eveningHours)) {
        $counter['eveningMinutes'] = $counter['eveningMinutes'] + 15;
    }

    if (in_array(date("H:i", strtotime($date['start_h_i'])), $nightHours)) {
        $counter['nightMinutes']  = $counter['nightMinutes'] + 15;
    }

    $date['start_h_i'] = date ("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime("+15 minutes", strtotime($date['start_h_i']))); // 15 minutes interval

} // end while
```

I hope someone can shine some light here, thanks!

Anyone?

Comment: Please share that loop, since that's really the code in question.

Comment: Why don't you just calculate `endTime - startTime`?

Comment: From what I've understood, you're listing `'00:00'` in both evening and night hours? Or is it a typo?

Comment: @ Fabricio, yes thats true. But i have also already tried to start nightHours array with 00:15.. but this doesn't help.

@animuson If you read my question correct.. im not trying to get the totalhours of the whole start and end time, i just need the hours for nighthours and eveninghours.. I need these hours to later calculate a extra % fee on top of the standard hourly rate.

Comment: @Wiseguy I've added the code to the post.

Comment: I'm going to go with the repetition of '00:00'. I wish I knew how to use a step debugger for PHP, but you should add some helpful echo's in there so you can see the state of $date and $counter as the loop is running.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
while (strtotime($date['start_h_i']) <= strtotime($date['end_h_i'])) {
```

to this:

```
while (strtotime($date['start_h_i']) < strtotime($date['end_h_i'])) {
```

The problem you're having is that you're updating the hours when you've already finished counting up time. So to use your own example of `00:30 - 00:45`:

- In loop first time: 00:30 <= 00:45, so add 15 minutes
- In loop second time: 00:45 <= 00:45, so add 15 minutes

By changing the `<=` to a `<` you remove that second operation: 00:45 !< 00:45 so add nothing.